# C# WPF - Toggle visibility of something isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf

Like button.IsVisible = false isn't working... It gives error:

> Property or indexer 'System.Windows.UIElement.IsVisible' cannot be
>   assigned to -- it is read only

I'm making a WPF application...

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Can you provide more information on you problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use `IsVisible` in WPF, you set the `Visibility` property:

```
button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Or, to make it visible:

```
button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Technically, there is also `Visibility.Hidden` which doesn't remove it from the layout. This isn't used very often, and is one of the "Know what you are doing before using" kind of options.